# Kibana cannot be accessed through port 5601 in browser

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I cannot get to kibana through web UI. I'm set the necessary ports in firewall-cmd, I've configured kibana.yml and elasticsearch.yml. I'm not seeing any relevant errors, or at least don't know if they are if they are there. It just shows 'Site cannot be reached' for the appropriate port.

Later on I would like to have put kibana on a subdomain kibana.domain.com, but I would first like to confirm that it's working without a subdomain.

I can confirm that my domain and nginx are working

Current versions:
OS - Centos 8
Elasticsearch - 7.10.2
Kibana - I have no clue how to get the version through terminal (there aren't version conflicts to my knowledge so it shouldn't matter. It's 7.x)

There is only one instance of kibana running on 5601 from what I can see.

`netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN`

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5601          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      290961/node
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1/systemd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      290425/nginx: maste
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4738/sshd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      290425/nginx: maste
tcp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                    LISTEN      1/systemd
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      290425/nginx: maste
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:9200          :::*                    LISTEN      287716/java
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:9300          :::*                    LISTEN      287716/java
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      4738/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      290425/nginx: maste
```

kibana.yml

```
server.port: 5601
server.host: "127.0.0.1"
elasticsearch.hosts: ["http://127.0.0.1:9200"]
```

elasticsearch.yml

```
cluster.name: portfolio_es_cluster
node.name: portfolio_es_node
path.data: /var/lib/elasticsearch
path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch
network.host: 127.0.0.1
http.port: 9200
```

Curl for kibana locally works

`curl -XGET http://localhost:5601/status -I`

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
content-security-policy: script-src 'unsafe-eval' 'self'; worker-src blob: 'self'; style-src 'unsafe-inline' 'self'
kbn-name: mykibananame
kbn-license-sig: d9d95bb2e2230b29804216ff76
content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
cache-control: private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
content-length: 121035
vary: accept-encoding
accept-ranges: bytes
Date: Mon, 18 Jan 2021 06:53:36 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
```

`firewall-cmd --list-all`

```
public (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: eth0 eth1
  sources:
  services: cockpit dhcpv6-client http https ssh
  ports: 5601/tcp 9200/tcp
  protocols:
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:
```

Comment: A service listening on localhost cannot be directly accessed from any other device.

Comment: @user9517 Sometimes we just need someone to point out our obvious and glaring mistakes. Thanks this was it.

Answer (score 2):

With the help of @user9517 asking if I'm aware that localhost and 127.0.0.1 (the same in the context of external connections in this case)
I was able to update the kibana.yml file with my server's IP

```
server.port: 5601
server.host: "serversIP"
elasticsearch.hosts: ["http://localhost:9200"] #this can remain as localhost if both Elasticsearch and Kibana are running on the same server.
```

And this answered a follow up I was bound to have as to why my proxy_pass to kibana wasn't working for a subdomain ie kibana.domain.com in my nginx systems. The proxy pass cannot be `proxy_pass localhost:5601` but rather `proxy_pass serversIP:5601`

Thanks again user9517.

Comment: server.port: 5601
server.host: "0.0.0.0"  // You can replace server.hot 0.0.0.0 to access from browser or other machine.